# boost_signals library missing when installing boost with brew

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew

After installing boost with brew:

```
brew install boost
brew link --overwrite boost
```

I found the library boost_signals is not installed.

When I build another project that depends on the boost_signals library using CMake, I got the following error message:

```
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_signals

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
```

I checked my /usr/local/lib, I see many boost libraries but lib boost_signals.dylib is nowhere to be found.

I am not sure how to install the additional Boost libraries like suggested by the error above.

My machine is running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Any pointers?

Thanks much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem this morning. From the [boost 1.69 release notes](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_69_0.html):

> Discontinued Libraries Signals (v1) is now removed. Its removal was
> announced in 1.68 and its deprecation was announced in 1.54. Boost
> 1.68 is the last release that provides this library. Users are encouraged to use Signals2 instead. The Boost community thanks Douglas
> Gregor for his work on Signals which served its users well and which
> also inspired Signals2.